# How to define variable globally

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I've setup `ssh-agent` as a systemd service on my Manjaro  (following directions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980986/7564988)). Along with the service itself, the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable needs to be set to `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket`. The above mentioned directions say to put this in `.zshrc` or equivalent. This works perfectly fine for most applications, as I primarily use commandline when needing to use ssh-agent.

However, when launching VSCode from dmenu, it does not run `.zshrc` and thus does not inherit the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. Thus to get it to work, I need to set the variable globally. Looking at the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables#Globally), the only way to do it (that I can see) is through `pam_env`. However, this did not work for me; I put

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK         DEFAULT=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket
```

in `/etc/environment`, but VSCode's `process.env` still does not have the variable defined. I also tried with

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK           DEFAULT=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket
```

and it still didn't set.

Note that this is definitely an environment issue as if I launch VSCode from a shell (when `.zshrc` is run), it does inherit `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. A very similar issue is [reported here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57488), but does not actually have a solution.

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the path instead of using the `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable? I doubt that will be set when the pam_env file is read. You can also try setting the variable in `/etc/environment`. Does that help? (should we assume you're using Arch?)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Arch (Manjaro). I can give hard coding the path a shot. Ideally I wouldn't, but ideal isn't always possible I suppose.

Comment: No, of course, but if it works if hard coded, we have a better idea of what a permanent solution would require.

Comment: Just tried it with `DEFAULT=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket` and it still didn't set.

Comment: @fra-san Hmmm. It doesn't work for me for whatever reason. Is there some additional configuration that I'd need to do other than literally just create the files? I see the manpage shows options and flags, but I can't actually run `pam_env.so`.

Comment: @fra-san I have now. Curiously, the variable is set when using `~/.pam_environment`, but not with `/etc/environment`. Along with those tests, I set a different test variable and it showed the same behavior. Also, for these tests, I've been rebooting the computer everytime. Is there a better/quicker way to test out `pam_env`?

Comment: Figured out why `/etc/environment` wasn't working; it takes `VARIABLE=value` as opposed to `~/.pam_environment` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` which takes `VARIABLE [DEFAULT=value] [OVERRIDE=value]`.

Comment: Alright, I think I've fully figured it out and posted an answer. I'd appreciate a read through to before I accept it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

In `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` add:

```bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK  DEFAULT=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket
```

### Other useful tidbits:

**Why didn't `/etc/environment` work originally?**:

`/etc/environment` follows a different format than either `~/.pam_environment` or `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, [as documented here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables#Using_pam_env):

`/etc/environment`:

```
VARIABLE=value
```

`~/.pam_environment` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`:

```
VARIABLE [DEFAULT=value] [OVERRIDE=value]
```

So I just had it in the wrong format.

**Why use `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` instead of the other two?**:

Because it was the only option that fully works now and will work in the future.

`/etc/environment` does not read environment variables in, thus `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}` does not work. You could hardcode the contents of `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, but the variable (and it's directory) are set by [`pam_systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) dynamically on a per-user basis. Thus, it's not a robust option.

`~/.pam_environment` will successfully accomplish the same task that `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` does, but it "is deprecated and will be removed at some point in the future" ([commit](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/commit/ecd526743a27157c5210b0ce9867c43a2fa27784)). So for future-proofing, it shouldn't be used.

And thus that leaves `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`. It works now with `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}` and isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

In my system `/usr/bin/code` is nothing more than a shell script.
You can modify it by putting additional export statements or call it from another script exporting required env vars first. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"

/usr/bin/code #path to your executable for VSCode
```

---

If we discuss X11 in Linux environment - the global environment settings for X11 session can be set in `/etc/X11/Xsession` or better in file put into directory `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`.

For the user settings use `$HOME/.xsession` or alternative `$HOME/.Xsession`, `$HOME/.xsessionrc`.

Usage of that files is included in main `/etc/X11/Xsession` (at least in my Debian system).

Comment: True. That might be the solution I end up going with, but I'd still be curious to know how to get an environment variable to be globally available.

Comment: Please see my proposal in edited answer.

Comment: `~/.xsession` didn't work either. To confirm, the script above does work for me. So I do at least have a work around now.

Comment: @JamesWright great! If this helps you, please remember to upvote it even if you don't accept this as the solution since it is only a workaround. Upvoting useful answers is essential.